# Isolating $k$ in $H_k=\frac{c}{k+1}$

Tags: harmonic-numbers

I am trying to find an equilibrium point of two algorithms, parametrized by $k$. The performance of the two algorithms:

- $\frac{c}{k+1}$ (where $c$ is some given positive constant)
- $H_k$ (the $k$-th harmonic number)

I am looking for a value $k$ such that $H_k=\frac{c}{k+1}$. I was able find a relatively close approximation using *product-log* ([Lambert **W** function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)). Set $k=e^{W(c)}-1$. This yields (using $e^{W(x)}=\frac{x}{W(x)}$):

- $\frac{c}{k+1}=\frac{c}{e^{W(c)}-1+1}=\frac{c}{e^{W(c)}}=\frac{c}{\frac{c}{W(c)}}=W(c)$
- $H_k=H_{e^{W(c)}-1}\approx\ln(e^{W(c)}-1)+ 1\approx W(c) + 1$

I wonder if there is a way to reach an exact solution, or, to have a solution that minimizes the difference between the two expressions.

Comment: It is hard to believe that there is a closed-form solution using well-known special functions, but at least we can tell that $k \approx c/\log c$ as $c\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us make to problem more general considering the equation to be
$$H_k=\frac c {k+a}$$ First, in order to limit the expansions to a single term, let $n=k+a$ making the equation
$$H_{n-a}=\frac c {n}$$ Assuming that $n$ is large, using
$$H_{n-a}=\gamma +\log
   \left({n}\right)+\frac{1-2a}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}
   \right)$$ and ignoring the higher order terms, we end with the equation
$$\gamma +\log
   \left({n}\right)+\frac{1-2a}{2n}=\frac c {n}$$ the solution of which being
$$n=\frac{2 a+2 c-1}{2 W\left(\frac{1}{2} (2 a+2 c-1)e^{\gamma } \right)}\implies \color{red}{k=\frac{2 a+2 c-1}{2 W\left(\frac{1}{2} (2 a+2 c-1)e^{\gamma } \right)}-a} \tag 1$$

As shown below for the case where $a=1$, the approximation is quite good even for  small values of $c$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
c & (1) & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.51307 &  0.53917 \\
 2 & 0.98203 &  1.00000 \\
 3 & 1.40552 &  1.41932 \\
 4 & 1.80033 &  1.81156 \\
 5  & 2.17472 &  2.18420 \\
 10 & 3.86345 &  3.86884 \\
 15 & 5.37830 &  5.38209 \\
 20 & 6.79327 &  6.79621 \\
 25 & 8.14014 &  8.14254 \\
 30 & 9.43626 &  9.43830 \\
 35 & 10.6924 &  10.6942 \\
 40 & 11.9159 &  11.9174 \\
 45 & 13.1119 &  13.1133 \\
 50 & 14.2843 &  14.2856 \\
 55 & 15.4362 &  15.4373 \\
 60 & 16.5698 &  16.5709 \\
 65 & 17.6873 &  17.6883 \\
 70 & 18.7901 &  18.7910 \\
 75 & 19.8795 &  19.8804 \\
 80 & 20.9568 &  20.9576 \\
 85 & 22.0228 &  22.0236 \\
 90 & 23.0785 &  23.0793 \\
 95 & 24.1246 &  24.1253 \\
 100 & 25.1616 &  25.1623
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Nuce work. Minor typo: oder -> order.

Comment: @martycohen. Thanks ! In fact, if you go to the edits, you would notice major differences  and improvements. By the way, about typo's, what means *nuce* ? **Happy New Year !**

Comment: It means that I sometimes don't proofread well.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, this is amazing, thank you!

Comment: @Elisha. You are very welcome ! I had fun with it !